# WPF: Context Menu dissapears after item update in my GridView

Tags: wpf, listview, contextmenu

so, I have this `ListView` in grid mode. I am dynamically updating it using a `CollectionView`. now, the problem I have is that when I open a context menu by right clicking on an item in my grid the context menu closes after the item updates--now, it is not a new item but it is the same item.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make the contet menu stay open after the item updates?

[Edit]
The grid is part of a public safety application that updates in near real-time. so the items are periodically added, removed, and updated.  If we right-click on an item to open the context menu and an update occurs before I can close it--even if the particular item does not change in any way--the context menu closes. The desired behavior is for the context menu to remain open.

Comment: Can you give us more information, why the item updates? Do you mean shifting from cell edit mode to browse mode?

Comment: This should work. Post you code if you need help fixing yours or search online for a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could supply your XAML that would help, but my guess is that you have defined the context menu on the `ListViewItem` element and that the menu closes because the whole ListViewItem is regenerated or replaced by WPF.

Perhaps you can define the context menu on the `ListView` instead? You will have to update your commands and get the selected item from the list when executing, since the context will no longer be a specific item.

Comment: yes, my context menu is on my item template. my other thought was to keep track and manually open the context menu--not the optimal solution.

Comment: this worked. I had to change my command execute code to get the item, but that was no big deal.